# Android Listprefence Value for Activity Loop Timer?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, timer, listpreference

Listprefence the selected value , SERVICE ACTIVITY in the loop time I want to use as the value.
But it is a kind of couldn't.

**PREFENCE CODE;**

```
NotificationTimer = (ListPreference) findPreference("nofication_timer");
if(NotificationTimer.getValue()==null) {
NotificationTimer.setValueIndex(0);
}
NotificationTimer.setSummary(NotificationTimer.getValue().toString());
NotificationTimer.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
@Override public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
preference.setSummary(newValue.toString() + " sn.");
return true;
}
});
```

**NOTİFİCATİON SERVİCE CODE;**

```
@Override public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
if (!isConnected){  
zamanlayici = new Timer();
yardimci = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
zamanlayici.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
@Override public void run() {
new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://"+URL+PORT+JSON);
}
}, 0, TİMER*1000); //LİSTPREFENCE SELECT VALUE
} else {
Toast.makeText(context, "Sunucu ile bağlantı kurulamadı !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
}
```

**ARRAY.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

<string-array name="updateInterval">
<item name="1dk">1 Dakika</item>
<item name="5dk">5 Dakika</item>
<item name="15dk">15 Dakika</item>
<item name="30dk">30 Dakika</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="updateIntervalValues">
<item name="1dk">60</item>
<item name="5dk">300</item>
<item name="15dk">900</item>
<item name="30dk">1800</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
}
```

Comment: What help do you exactly want? Please explain your question in a better way.

Comment: The aim here is to secielen according to the value in the JSON data to read.


"}, 0, TİMER*1000); //LİSTPREFENCE SELECT VALUE"


TIMER = LİSTPREFENCE SELECT VALUE

Comment: Sorry. Can't understand your Language.

Comment: "}, 0, TİMER*1000); //LİSTPREFENCE SELECT VALUE" 

OK!!!!